# google big query on sorting unique combination of multiple columns

Tags: sql, distinct, google-bigquery, web-traffic, referrals

We already have a table of all referral of a website: ( one entry per referral )

```
String : referral
String : target
integer: date
```

Now, we want to use big query to sort all referrals based on counts, like:

```
referral       : target,         count:

google.com/... : welcome.html,   28353 
bing.com/...   : welcome.html,   5334 
gmail.com/...  : about.html,     343
...
```

What should the big query sql be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why not just group by both columns?

```
SELECT referral, target, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM [mydataset.referrallog] 
GROUP BY referral, target
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

if I got you right, so:

```
SELECT COUNT(path) AS path_count, path
FROM (
  SELECT concat(referrer, target) AS path
  FROM [mydataset.referrallog])
GROUP BY path ORDER BY path_count DESC;
```

Comment: I have to remove "distinct", so it outputs count correctly. "SELECT count (path), path FROM (select concat(referrer, target) as path FROM [mydataset.referrallog]) group by path"

Comment: But this sql hasn't sort the result based on count yet.

Comment: So the final answer is "SELECT count (path) as path_count, path FROM (select concat(referrer, target) as path FROM [mydataset.referrallog]) group by path order by path_count desc".

Comment: user1516770: If you can edit your original answer, I will approve it!